# How to display total and grouped value for each month in same column chart SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

For each Month I need to display TotalMonthlyBudget vs TotalMonthlyActual(which is works fine), but  then I need EarthquakeBudget vs EarthquakeActual and WindBudget vs WindActual and all that for each month in same chart. I am using Column Chart. I am using visual studio 2010.

So I need something like that:

[image]

But I cant understand how to do that in SSRS?
I only able to bring TotalMonthlyBudget vs TotalMonthlyActual.(on a picture below)

[image]

This is in design mode:

[image]

So how can I get the rest of what I need?

Comment: ...Drag more fields into the values pane?  What am I missing?